# Setting \parindent to 2em or \quad

Tags: spacing, indentation, paragraphs

I would like to set `\parindent` to `2em` (or `\quad` which is the same if I know correctly). How can I do it?

`\setlength{\parindent}{...}` only accepts values with length units, for example, `15pt`, `1cm`, etc. It doesn't accept `\quad`; it gives the error "Illegal unit of measure".

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\setlength{\parindent}{\quad}
\begin{document}
A
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\parindent=2em\relax`  Note that `\quad` is not a length, but a macro for skipping a length, so one cannot set `\parindent` to it.

Comment: `\quad` is a skip of `1em`, so `\setlength{\parindent}{1em}` should do the trick.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`\quad` means `\hskip 1em\relax`. You have to give a length directly as the argument to `\parindent`. So use `\setlength{\parindent}{2em}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe}  %% just for demo
\setlength{\parindent}{2em}
\begin{document}
A\\
\hspace*{2em}A
\end{document}
```

[image]

You can find the meaning of `\quad` by `texdef \quad` in terminal. And to find the value of `\parindent`, put `\showthe\parindent` in your file and the value will be show in the log.

Comment: `\AtBeginDocument{\setlength{\parskip}{1em}}` is better. Why? Well, exercise for you.

Comment: @egreg For me? :-) May be I am a lazy student who runs out of time quickly these days. :-)